# How to take $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x^5+x^{10}}}$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have the integral:

$$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x^5+x^{10}}}$$

I have no clue how to approach it. i  was thinking of $x = \frac{1}{t}$ but it does not seem to be correct, or I do something wrong

Comment: Have you tried $x^5=t$? then $5dx=x^{-4} dt$ and you'll get something like $\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun $x=1/t$ and get

$$\int_0^1 dt \frac{t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^5+t^{10}}} = \frac15 \int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u+u^2}}$$

You should be able to do the latter integral.  The result is $\frac15 \log{(1+2/\sqrt{3})}$.

Comment: Excellent $(+1)$

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong since I get $\frac{1}{5} \log \left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: you did nothing wrong - I did.  Messed up the integration limits.

Comment: This was just a very minor detail ! The solution you provided is really nice. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\root{1 + x^{5} + x^{10}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{5}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 5}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\root{1 + x + x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ =\ \pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{2t - 1}}{=}\,\,\,
{2 \over 5}\int_{\root{3} - 1}^{1/2}{\dd t \over t^{2} - 1} =
\bbx{{1 \over 5}\,\ln\pars{1 + {2\root{3} \over 3}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> The change of variables in \eqref{1} is [Euler First Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_first_substitution_of_Euler).